# Existing Database for Nutrition Facts?

Tags: model-view-controller, database-design

I'm developing an ecommerce store using MVC and it will feature various health food products. We would like to display the Nutrition Facts label for each product, and am wondering if there is an existing way to do this dynamically without images and if there is a database out there with all the facts we can pull from, to minimize data entry off the bat. I'm not sure if this is a stack-overflow appropriate question, but I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

**Edit**

I've found this website http://www.myfitnesspal.com/food/calorie-chart-nutrition-facts  which has alot of the products that I need that are missing from databases such as the USDA's. What's the best way of collecting this information?

Comment: You might want to read the part about "Personal Use" in their Terms Of Use before planning to collect this information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how complete it is with regard to packaged and processed food, but the database available from the USDA was a good start when I was trying to accomplish a similar task.

It is in Access, unfortunately.

[Download from the USDA](http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=18879)

Comment: http://www.myfitnesspal.com/food/calorie-chart-nutrition-facts

I found this site, which has alot of the products that I need that are missing from databases such as the USDA's. What's the best way of collecting this information?

Answer (score 4):

The USDA database has about 10,000 records, and it quite annoying to work with.

There are a number of Nutrition APIs out there:

- http://www.nutritionix.com/api (includes USDA, 200K upcs, around 300K items total)
- http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/ (unknown # items)